# condition for a general map (not necessarily continuous) between two complete metric spaces to be a closed map

Tags: general-topology

A map $f:X\rightarrow Y$ between complete metric spaces, is a closed map if for any cauchy sequence $\{ y_n \}_1^\infty$ in $f(X)$ there exists a cauchy sequence $\{ x_n \}_1^\infty$ such that $\{ f(x_n) \}_1^\infty$ = $\{ y_n \}_1^\infty$ for every $n$.

My attempt: Taking $A$ a close set in $X$, assuming $f(A)$ is not closed, therefore there is a missing accumulation point $y\in f(A)$. If we take a cauchy sequence $\{ y_n \}_1^\infty \subset f(A)$ from $B(y,\frac{1}{n})$, We get a cauchy sequence $\{ x_n \}_1^\infty \subset A$ such that $\{ f(x_n) \}_1^\infty$ = $\{ y_n \}_1^\infty$. 
$A$ is a closed set in $X$ therefore a complete set, so $\{ x_n \}_1^\infty \rightarrow x\in A$. And there is where I'm stuck, cause $f$ is not necessarily continuous, so we can't assure $f(x) = y$.

Comment: thanks for English corrections!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The claim is wrong even for contuinuous $f$, as the following counterexample shows. Let $X=\Bbb R^2$ and $Y=\Bbb R$ endowed with the standard metrics. Let $f:X\to Y$ be a projection onto the first coordinate. Then for any Cauchy sequence $\{ y_n \}_1^\infty$ in $f(X)$ a sequence $\{(y_n,0) \}_1^\infty$ is Cauchy and $f(y_n,0)=y_n$ for every $n$. Nevertheless, the map $f$ is not closed, because its image of a closed set $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2: xy=1\}$ is a non-closed set $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$.

> We get a cauchy series $\{ x_n \}_1^\infty \subset A$ such that $\{ f(x_n) \}_1^\infty$ = $\{ y_n \}_1^\infty$.

You can find such a sequence $\{ x_n \}_1^\infty$ in $X$, but not necessarily in $A$.